# Stack Based Column Sum in a data frame using R

Tags: r, column-sum

My existing data frame looks line given below

```
NAV_Date    NAV    Year  Day       Units   Amount  Balance_Units
2013-06-01  282.5  2013  Saturday  3.540   1000    3.540
2013-06-08  279.3  2013  Saturday  3.581   1000    3.581
2013-06-15  276.0  2013  Saturday  3.623   1000    3.623
2013-06-22  261.6  2013  Saturday  3.822   1000    3.822
2013-06-29  273.3  2013  Saturday  3.659   1000    3.659
```

I want my new data frame to have Balance_Units column have entries like given below using R Language
i.e Balance unit column should be the sum of previous value and present value 
This is need to be done on the list of dataframe

```
NAV_Date    NAV    Year  Day       Units   Amount  Balance_Units
2013-06-01  282.5  2013  Saturday  3.540   1000    3.540
2013-06-08  279.3  2013  Saturday  3.581   1000    7.121
2013-06-15  276.0  2013  Saturday  3.623   1000    10.744
2013-06-22  261.6  2013  Saturday  3.822   1000    14.566
2013-06-29  273.3  2013  Saturday  3.659   1000    18.225
```

I tried this but , this is not working

```
 for( i in 1:length(W)) {
  W[[i]]$Units  = 1000/W[[i]]$NAV
  W[[i]]$Amount = 1000
  W[[i]]$Balance_Units = 0
  W[[i]]$Balance_Units = W[[i]]$Units + W[[i]]$Balance_Units
   }
```

Comment: Do you want cumulative sum (shown in your current post) or sum of current row + previous row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a convenient function `cumsum` in `base R`

```
df1$Balance_Units <- cumsum(df1$Balance_Units)
```

---

With `dplyr`, it can be created within `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Balance_Units = cumsum(Balance_Units))
```

---

If 'W' is a `list` of `data.frame`s, we can use `lapply`

```
W <- lapply(W, transform, Balance_Units = cumsum(Balance_Units))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(NAV_Date = c("2013-06-01", "2013-06-08", "2013-06-15", 
"2013-06-22", "2013-06-29"), NAV = c(282.5, 279.3, 276, 261.6, 
273.3), Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L), Day = c("Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday"), Units = c(3.54, 
3.581, 3.623, 3.822, 3.659), Amount = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 
1000L, 1000L), Balance_Units = c(3.54, 3.581, 3.623, 3.822, 3.659
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hello @akrun, just a question: how do you take the table posted by the OP, in order to avoid typing one by one to test the code?

Comment: @Alexis Just use `soread()` from [overflow](https://github.com/mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab) after copy/paste in clipboard

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` solution. I added something for sequential sum as well..

```
library(data.table) 
> dat
     NAV_Date   NAV Year      Day Units Amount Balance_Units
1: 2013-06-01 282.5 2013 Saturday 3.540   1000         3.540
2: 2013-06-08 279.3 2013 Saturday 3.581   1000         3.581
3: 2013-06-15 276.0 2013 Saturday 3.623   1000         3.623
4: 2013-06-22 261.6 2013 Saturday 3.822   1000         3.822
5: 2013-06-29 273.3 2013 Saturday 3.659   1000         3.659

# Cumulative sum
> dat[, cumulative_sum := cumsum(Balance_Units)]
> dat
     NAV_Date   NAV Year      Day Units Amount Balance_Units cumulative_sum
1: 2013-06-01 282.5 2013 Saturday 3.540   1000         3.540          3.540
2: 2013-06-08 279.3 2013 Saturday 3.581   1000         3.581          7.121
3: 2013-06-15 276.0 2013 Saturday 3.623   1000         3.623         10.744
4: 2013-06-22 261.6 2013 Saturday 3.822   1000         3.822         14.566
5: 2013-06-29 273.3 2013 Saturday 3.659   1000         3.659         18.225

# Sequential sum
> dat[, sequential_sum := Balance_Units + shift(x = Balance_Units, fill = 0)]
> dat
     NAV_Date   NAV Year      Day Units Amount Balance_Units cumulative_sum sequential_sum
1: 2013-06-01 282.5 2013 Saturday 3.540   1000         3.540          3.540          3.540
2: 2013-06-08 279.3 2013 Saturday 3.581   1000         3.581          7.121          7.121
3: 2013-06-15 276.0 2013 Saturday 3.623   1000         3.623         10.744          7.204
4: 2013-06-22 261.6 2013 Saturday 3.822   1000         3.822         14.566          7.445
5: 2013-06-29 273.3 2013 Saturday 3.659   1000         3.659         18.225          7.481
```